# GWT: Detect if Spacebar is held down during ClickEvent

Tags: gwt, keycode

I've extended a label in GWT and added a clickEvent. Right now I have it successfully detecting if Control or Alt was held during the click on the label, but ideally I want to have it check if spacebar was held down. Is there any way this is possible? Thanks. Current code is below.

```
public class CategoryLabel extends Label {
    public class CategoryLabelHandler implements ClickHandler {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            CategoryLabel cl = (CategoryLabel) event.getSource();
            boolean altDown = event.isAltKeyDown();
            boolean ctrlDown = event.isControlKeyDown();

            doStuff(cl, altDown, ctrlDown); //Etc. 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the NativeEvent to get the keyCode of it:

```
NativeEvent nativeEvent  = event.getNativeEvent();
int keyCode = nativeEvent.getKeyCode();
if(keyCode == 32){}
```

Here is a full list of all possible keyCodes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event/UIEvent/KeyEvent

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. This isn't exactly what I wanted because inside a ClickEvent this will only return the keycode for the mouse button that caused the event. I don't think it's possible to check if other buttons are being held besides the standard modifiers (ctrl, alt, shift, etc). I used this code elsewhere to set booleans that a key had been pressed and then checked them in the ClickHandler onClick. It's not good to see if buttons are being held, but can be used to check if it had been pressed previously (and you can then set them to false to do it again).